# CDT Folder issue when developing an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

I have integrated a propertytester for my eclipse plugin.
Everytime i am selecting an item from the context menu the property tester will be activated and checks, what datatype the selected element is, e.g. **IProject** or **IFolder**.
The recognition worked perfectly, until i did install the CDT plugin to eclipse.
Now the folders seem to be represented as type **org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CContainer**, which seems to be a CDT representation of the folder.
Is there a way to avoid this conversion mechanism or to convert the CDT foldertype **org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CContainer** programmatically to the known **IFolder**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User interface objects normally are 'adaptable' to resource objects.

So try

```
IFolder folder = (IFolder)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(object, IFolder.class);
```

where `object` is the selected object.

It is possible that an adapter directly to `IFolder` is not provided so also try adapting to `IResource`.

In newer versions of Eclipse the adapter manager is generic so you don't need the cast.

In Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) you can use:

```
IFolder folder = Adapters.adapt(object, IFolder.class);
```

which will also check if the class implements `IAdaptable` or is an instance of `IFolder`. Only use this if you only want your code to run in Eclipse 4.6 (and later).

Comment: In Eclipse Neon there is a great new utility class called "Adapters". It implements the canonical way of adapting an object, even one that may already implement the given interface: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Adapters.html

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, it solved my issue. Didn't know that everything is adaptable :)

Comment: @JonahGraham: Thank u too, very interesting